# Only dummy output available for audio on linux

Tags: linux, drivers, audio

Ok so, I have Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon installed. But I installed also `xfce4` and `openbox` and am using xfce4 desktop environment with openbox.

At first, I had few issues with audio volume control and their keybindings. I tried to write script to decrease the audio volume and bind it to the fn key combination. But I messed up even more.
I tried to remove and reinstalled `alsamixer`, `pavucontrol`, `pulseaudio`, and few other few other audio related packages.
But now, the audio is completely destroyed. `pavucontrol` now only shows "Dummy Output" as available output device.

`$ pacmd list-sinks` shows 1 sink available with the `device.description = "Dummy Output"`.
Built-in sink and USB audio device are not detected.

when I try to `$ sudo alsa force-reload`, I get the following:
`Unloading  ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).`
`Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).`

My guess is that I somehow broke the audio drivers. I don't know what to do now.

For what it's worth, I am very well in the audio group.